# Кроме вывода "print" PyCharm больше ничего не отображает

Tags: python, консоль, pycharm, print

Решил задачу. Stepik проверил и пропустил (выполнение точное). Ввожу эту же задачу в PyCharm, на выходе пустота. Для проверки ввёл две строки print("hell") и print(2), далее две строки задачки. На выходе, всё что ниже двух первых строк не отображается, ошибку не выдаёт. Помогите понять, в чём загвоздка. Выложил скрин.

Заметил, что кроме "print" PyCharm больше ничего отображать не хочет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код в текст помещайте. И что за "ть не хочет."? Но учтите, что у вас PyCharm ввода ждет. Stepik его делает, а вы?

Comment: Он ждет от вас ответа, напишите какое-либо число в консоль

Comment: Ну так там input, а оно заставляет интерпретатор подождать ввода от пользователя, что собственно и происходит. А вот поддерживает ли эта идея полноценно терминал Я не знаю.

Comment: Так этот код дальше ждёт ввода с клавиатуры. Введите что-нибудь и нажмите Enter

Comment: Используйте input с аргументом, например, `a = int(input("Введите a: "))`, чтобы было видно, когда программа от вас чего-то ждет

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения.  До блондина дошло.

Answer (score 3):

На скриншоте Вы в переменную `a` сохраняете ваш ввод текста в виде числа. После того как PyCharm вывел вам ваши принты, он перешел к переменной `a`, и ждет от вас ответа, пока вы ему что-нибудь напечатаете. Только после этого он вам выведет ваше число